# ChromeDriver fails to launch

Tags: angular, webdriver, protractor, cucumber

I'm following along with the article at https://medium.com/spektrakel-blog/angular-protractor-and-cucumber-552bd75ff6c9. I downloaded and executed the tests his github at https://github.com/spektrakel-blog/angular-protractor-cucumber.

However, my ChromeDriver fails to start with the following error.

```
$ protractor "--baseUrl" "https://angular.io"
[14:15:49] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[14:15:49] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
Unhandled rejection Error: empty stack
    at pop (/Users/svuong/WebstormProjects/angular-protractor-cucumber-master/node_modules/cucumber-tag-expressions/lib/tag_expression_parser.js:82:35)
```

When I look the chrome window, the address bar is

> data:,

I'm using Node version v6.11.0. Thoughts as to why this is happening?

Comment: are you sure your chromedriver is the most current version?  using an outdated version of chromedriver is the most common cause of issues like this where webdriver can't even get going and connected to the browser

Answer (score 1):

Before running the tests displays always data:; ,so this is correct behavior. Please check what is the url that should be opened. Posting some code can help also.